# I am using Email extension plugin with Hudson. There is only TO list option available with the plugin. Is there any way I can add CC options?

Tags: cc, email-ext

emailext body: readFile("${workspace}/email.html"),subject: "${SUBJECT}.",mimeType: 'text/html', to: 'xxx@email.com,cc: yyy@email.com.com'

emails are being sent to everyone in the 'to' field instead of being sent 'to' to and 'cc' separately,

provide sample working code with cc `your text`